# In Eve, how can you store the user's password securely?

Tags: python, eve

If you put a debugger in the run file, you will see that the user's password is hashed, but when you look in the mongo collection, the user's password is stored in plain text. How do you save the user's password as a hash?

Here are my files:

run.py:

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import BasicAuth

import bcrypt

class BCryptAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        # use Eve's own db driver; no additional connections/resources are used
        accounts = app.data.driver.db["accounts"]
        account = accounts.find_one({"username": username})
        return account and \
            bcrypt.hashpw(password, account['password']) == account['password']

def create_user(*arguments, **keywords):
    password = arguments[0][0]['password']
    username = arguments[0][0]['username']
    user = {
        "password": bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()),
        "username": username,
    }
    return post_internal("accounts", user)


app = Eve(auth=BCryptAuth)
app.on_insert_accounts += create_user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

settings.py:

```
API_NAME = "gametest"

CACHE_CONTROL = "max-age=20"
CACHE_EXPIRES = 20
MONGO_DBNAME = "gametest"
MONGO_HOST = "localhost"
MONGO_PORT = 27017
PUBLIC_ITEM_METHODS = ["GET"]
RESOURCE_METHODS = ["GET"]

accounts_schema = {
    "username": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": True,
        "unique": True,
    },
    "password": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": True,
    },
}

accounts = {
    # the standard account entry point is defined as
    # '/accounts/<ObjectId>'. We define  an additional read-only entry
    # point accessible at '/accounts/<username>'.
    "additional_lookup": {
        "url": "regex('[\w]+')",
        "field": "username",
    },

    # We also disable endpoint caching as we don't want client apps to
    # cache account data.
    "cache_control": "",
    "cache_expires": 0,

    # Finally, let's add the schema definition for this endpoint.
    "schema": accounts_schema,
    "public_methods": ["POST"],
    "resource_methods": ["POST"],
}
games_schema = {
    "game_id": {
        "type": "objectid",
        "required": True
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": True
    },
}

games = {
    "item_title": "game",
    "schema": games_schema,
}

orders = {
    "schema": {
        "game": {
            "type": "objectid",
            "required": True,
        },
    },
    "resource_methods": ["GET", "POST"],
}

DOMAIN = {
    "accounts", accounts,
    "orders": orders,
    "games": game,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few major things in your `run.py` that were preventing you from authenticating:

- In your `create_user` event hook you were generating a salt with `bcrypt.gensalt()`, but you weren't saving the salt anywhere. Salts are useful for preventing [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks, but you need to save them so that when you try to hash the password again you get the same result.
- You're using the `on_insert_accounts` event hook to modify the document before it's posted, but then returning a `post_internal` instead of letting the event hook run its course. This *might* work, but I feel like you should just use the event hook as it was intended.

Here is the modified `run.py`:

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import BasicAuth

import bcrypt

class BCryptAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        # use Eve's own db driver; no additional connections/resources are used
        accounts = app.data.driver.db["accounts"]
        account = accounts.find_one({"username": username})
        return account and \
            bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), account['salt'].encode('utf-8')) == account['password']

def create_user(documents):
    for document in documents:
        document['salt'] = bcrypt.gensalt().encode('utf-8')
        password = document['password'].encode('utf-8')
        document['password'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password, document['salt'])

app = Eve(auth=BCryptAuth)
app.on_insert_accounts += create_user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

There were a few typos in your `settings.py`, so I'm including a working version here for good measure:

```
API_NAME = "gametest"

CACHE_CONTROL = "max-age=20"
CACHE_EXPIRES = 20
MONGO_DBNAME = "gametest"
MONGO_HOST = "localhost"
MONGO_PORT = 27017
PUBLIC_ITEM_METHODS = ["GET"]
RESOURCE_METHODS = ["GET"]

accounts_schema = {
    "username": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": True,
        "unique": True
    },
    "password": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": True
    }
}

accounts = {
    # the standard account entry point is defined as
    # '/accounts/<ObjectId>'. We define  an additional read-only entry
    # point accessible at '/accounts/<username>'.
    "additional_lookup": {
        "url": "regex('[\w]+')",
        "field": "username",
    },

    # We also disable endpoint caching as we don't want client apps to
    # cache account data.
    "cache_control": "",
    "cache_expires": 0,

    # Finally, let's add the schema definition for this endpoint.
    "schema": accounts_schema,
    "public_methods": ["POST"],
    "resource_methods": ["POST"]
}
games_schema = {
    "game_id": {
        "type": "objectid",
        "required": True
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": True
    }
}

games = {
    "item_title": "game",
    "schema": games_schema
}

orders = {
    "schema": {
        "game": {
            "type": "objectid",
            "required": True,
        }
    },
    "resource_methods": ["GET", "POST"]
}

DOMAIN = {
    "accounts": accounts,
    "orders": orders,
    "games": games
}
```

Comment: `document['salt'] = bcrypt.gensalt()` and `bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), account['salt']) == account['password']`, and it worked. Thank you Jen.

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this to store my users password securely and block admin creation without authorization key:

```
class TokenAuthCutom(TokenAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        payload = decode_token(token)
        # check if payload is valid and if allowed_roles is not empty check if role is valid
        return payload and (not allowed_roles or payload['roles'] in allowed_roles)

def before_insert_user(documents):
    body = request.get_json(force=True)
    admin_key = body.get('admin_register_key')
    for document in documents:
        password = document['password'].encode('utf-8')
        document['password'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')
        document['roles'] = 'admin' if admin_key is not None and admin_key == ADMIN_REGISTER_KEY else 'client'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve(auth=TokenAuthCutom)
    app.on_insert_users += before_insert_user
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT)
```