# What is the format of the request for authentication to python-eve api

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, authentication, token, eve

I, basically, have two related questions.

In my case, I have a global Mongo authentication as **admin** with the password **pass**. I implemented my `BCryptAuth` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30862524/1329187), so I can create users without any authentication like this:

```
curl -d 'username="barack"' -d 'password="obama"' http://0.0.0.0:5000/users/?pretty
```

Then, I can access my api using my Mongo authentication like this:

```
curl -u admin:pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/users/?pretty
```

But I cannot use any of my new user's credentials to get any data. So, the request

```
curl -u barack:obama http://0.0.0.0:5000/users/?pretty
```

does not work. I always get **401**:

```
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Please provide proper credentials"
    }
}
```

In [this example](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#global-authentication), after implementing basic authentication, the request is the following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0" -i http://example.com
```

It is not clear for me what the token after the `Basic` keyword is. I also tried to use this format in my case, but nothing works.

So, the first question is, what must be the format of the request as the **barack** user with the password **obama** for the **BasicAuth**?

Also, I am trying to implement the `TokenAuth`. Then the second question is, what is the format of the request with the token?

I could not find any clear information about this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @gcw, I figured out how to make the request using the **Authorization** header.

Couple of remarks:

- The Base64 decoding on linux is done with `echo '<base64encodedstring>' | base64 -d`. The `-D` is the macos option.
- The Base64 encoding is done with: `echo -n '<string>' | base64`. The `-n` is important - it drops the `new line` character, which is by default included in the `<string>`.

**But I still was not able to use my newly created users to login to the api.**

Comment: The Authorization header must have the "admin:pass" information in base 64 format. If you check the contents of `YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0` by decoding it with `echo "YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0" | base64 -D` you can see that it is `admin:secret`. Try to use your credentials in base 64 format to see if that works. Also, you can generate the Authorization header using Postman Basic Auth tab.

Comment: @gcw, oh, that explains all. Thank you. You may want to make it an answer, I will accept it, if it works for me. Is it the same for the other new users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Authorization header must have the `admin:pass` information in base64 format. If you check the contents of YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0 by decoding it with `echo "YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0" | base64 -D` you can see that it is `admin:secret`. Try to use your credentials in base64 format to see if that works. Also, you can generate the Authorization header using Postman Basic Auth tab.

About using the TokenAuth, you can use `Bearer` instead of `Basic` to pass your token in base64 format. This answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re#120244) explains some details about different HTTP authentication methods.